# Add tags for early, high, and late Middle Ages?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we add tags for early, high, and late Middle Ages? My rep is not sufficient to add tags myself.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect a newcomer - particularly who isn't familiar with the time period - will have a much easier time picking "Middle Ages" than they will trying to figure out which of the three tags is most adequate.

Also, at least one of the suggested tags has a synonym:

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/early-medieval

Comment: To address that concern you could also keep the [tag:middle-ages] tag. So then you'd have 4 tags about the Middle Ages: early, high, late, and a "generic" one. If that's too granular then I suppose you would only go with the single generic tag. Maybe time will tell if there are enough questions about the period to warrant additional tags. For now, if you stick with just one generic tag then it would be left to the user to clarify in their question what part of the period they are asking about, if that is indeed relevant.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, We can write correct guideline in Usage excerpt. But that doesn't stop users from misusing existing tags so I don't see how it will help in this case. One blanket tag it is then!